# Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x+y) = F(x) + F(y)$

Tags: derivatives

Find $F'(x)$ if  $F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$

I'm not sure how to differentiate the first term with respect to $x$. 
And is $\dfrac{dF(y)}{dx} = \dfrac{dF(y)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx} = F'(y) F'(x)$

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Presumably $y$ doesn't depend on $x$? In that case you can treat it as a constant.

Comment: The given condition doesn't actually establish that $F$ is continuous. Adding that assumption, the answers here are good.

Answer (score 5):

$F(0)=F(0)+F(0)\Rightarrow F(0)=0$

$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x)+F(h)-F(x)}{h}\\=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h}=F'(0)$

(Assuming $F$ is differentiable at $x=0$, also assuming the functional equation is defined $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $F(0)=0$. Suppose that $F$ is differentable at $0$, then
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(h)}{h}=F'(0)
$$
So $F'(x)=F'(0)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Remark: The functional equation has everywhere non continuous solutions. Differentability at zero, implies $F$ is linear.

Comment: Is differentiability at zero required, or is continuity sufficient to establish both in this case?

Comment: Continuity at zero, that is.

Comment: This condition can be replaced with weaker conditions like, boundedness in an arbitrary open interval.